# Call a function on terminating/exiting a lua script (an atexit()/cleaning function)

Tags: lua

**Question:** Is there a way to call a function when the lua script is terminated by either the system or a program which has started the script (e.g. a C program)? An atexit()/cleaning function for lua.

**The situation:** a external C program (call it PROG) manages a lua script (call it SCRIPT) and calls its functions, the lua script uses a separated library (.so, cal it LIB) which reserves resources which should be freed when the lua script exits. The lua script is managed (and thus terminated) by PROG which i can not alter. SCRIPT should notify LIB when it is terminated.

How can this be done?
Note: i'm fairly new to lua so please also explain your answer, much appreciated :)

I'm on Linux using Lua 5.3.1

---

Currently this seem to work:

```
a = {__gc = function() print'exit function from LIB called' end}
setmetatable(a,a)
```

Comment: Can you call the C function [lua_close](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_close) and use [userdata with __gc](http://www.lua.org/pil/29.html)?

Comment: I can not call the lua_close function that would be for the managing C program. I've reformulated my question slightly because i think it was unclear. I want a sort of atexit() function for lua, which will call a function from my library to clean up its resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2001-08/msg00265.html

You may need to run lua_runprotected call to prevent a stack under flow problem.

Comment: Not really what i was looking but i found what i ment: http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2009-09/msg00147.html Unfortunately uses the deprecated newproxy(true) so is no longer feasible.